# How to update QTableView when database updated?

Tags: database, qt, tableview

I use `QSqlRelationalTableModel` to extract data from database, and use `tableView` to show it. Now, when I update my database, how to update `tableView` automatically to show it? I know i need to use function `dataChanged()` to make this automatically, but i do not know how to use it? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

The main code is as follows:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(NULL, db);
model->setTable(tableName);
model->select();
tableView->setModel(model);
tableView->show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no need to use `dataChanged()`.

You just need to call [`QSqlRelationalTableModel::select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#select) whenever the database gets updated. This will re-populate the model from the database, and update the views that are using it automatically.

- **If the database is updated from within you application**, you can just call `model->select()` after the update queries get executed in your application.
- **If the database is updated from another application**, you'll have to use something like [PostgreSQL's event notification system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html), subscribe to the notification from your application using [`QSqlDriver::subscribeToNotification()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#subscribeToNotification) and call `model->select()` in a slot connected to the [`notification()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#notification-1) signal.

  You can use [`QSqlDriver::hasFeature(QSqlDriver::EventNotifications)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#hasFeature) to check if notifications from your database are supported.